# I need a permalink post_type structure with taxonomy slug in it for location landing pages and service pages

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I am building a Wordpress site that has landing pages for locations in the UK. Each location needs sub pages to represent a service relevant to that location.

To do this, I have set up service pages under a custom post type, and have a custom taxonomy assigned to that CPT called 'Locations'. I have assigned the locations to the corresponding service pages.

I would like the Location page to be accessible at **[www.domain.com/location-name/](http://www.domain.com/location-name/)** and the assigned service pages to be accessible at **[www.domain.com/location-name/service-name](http://www.domain.com/location-name/service-name)**. (I plan to make the content of the service pages dynamic, so I don't create 100's of duplicate pages.)

I am trying to use Custom Post Type UI plugin to do this, but I am struggling to rewrite the URL so it has the format of **[www.domain.com/location-name/service-name/](http://www.domain.com/location-name/service-name/)**.

I am really struggling to get this to work. Should I be using custom code in functions.php instead?